# Google In-App billing returns RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE when Market is not working

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have this minor issue on my head - I've integrated Android Market In-app Billing in py project using the official sample "Dungeons".

It's working smoothly for now, I've discovered only one small problem - when I select "Force stop" & "Clear data" (note: not "cache" but "data") in Market application details or when I reset the phone (which is more or less the same) - I receive `RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE` when I check for the service.

Of course, this is normal, since all the market data is cleared and after I've discussed it whit my boss we've decided to leave it like this - it's a corner case and it's not fatal.

But now our QA is reporting that sometimes she has to start the market at least twice before the in-app billing is available. I don't like this but I don't know what can I do to fix it - starting the market from our application is not an option. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your just not trying to do something before the service has been bound?

Comment: Yes + I don't experience this problem when I install the application on device on which the market is already running.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by already running. Why would anyone ever Force Stop the Market app. Obviously you will get an error if you do that.

Comment: As I said - it's a corner case. What worries me is that my QA said that she had to open the market twice sometimes before the service becomes available - what if the user makes a factory reset, then opens the market, downloads my application and the service is still unavailable? It's not a big deal, I know... I just wanted to ask in case there is some solution.

Comment: Why does your QA know opening the market app twice would make it work? I think there's a clear flaw in your process. You need to get this down to a reproduceable error.

Comment: It is giving me same error and its too complicated, I have figured out the problem. They are starting service in very wearied way and also they are not stopping that service.. (billingservice) see how they started and how they finished it using undocumented ways. :(

Comment: would you like to share your simple code sample please .

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, I am in one month vacation to take my final exams at my university. My simple code is Google's simple code in it's core. The only difference is that I make the key checks on the server. Well we decided to leave the code like this and my boss haven't called me to tell me that there are issues with the clients. I don't think that it is a problem on our side so I guess android team will fix it.

Comment: @Elena +1 for insisting on understanding why things don't work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today on a Motorola Razr.

Make sure your device doesn't have extra accounts. If there is an extra account, it can cause RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE even if a valid account is there.